# Given is physical address. What is the address of the beginning of the segment? x86

Tags: memory, x86

Given is physical address.  What is the address of the beginning of the segment? x86

Adress 1A32H

Can someone explain me how it works and how to find the beginning of the segment in it ?

Answer (score 0):

There’s no answer for this.

If the question were asking about 8086, the segment base could be any multiple of 16: 0, 10, 20, ... up to 1A30. It could even be F1A40, F1A50, ... up to FFFF0.

But x86 generally refers to 32 bit protected mode, in which case the segment can be literally any 32 bit value.